# Protractor Get Model Value

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

I am new to ProtractorJS.
What I am trying to do is trying to get the value of a disabled input element. 
This input element is bound to a model. Initially this input element is empty; then after some action the model value is updated (and thus displayed in input element). I need to get that value, how can I do that ?

My input element is:

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" style="font-size: 11px;" disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-model="Promotion.PrometricID">
```

I am trying to fetch value by:

```
element(by.model("Promotion.PrometricID")).getAttribute('value');
```

But whenever I write the value in console it gives me "[object] [object]".

Can anyone please tell me how to find value in this text box or in model ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is just because `getAttribute()` **returns a promise**.

You need to **resolve it** if you want to see the result on the console:

```
var elm = element(by.model("Promotion.PrometricID"));
elm.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

FYI, exploring [The WebDriver Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#the-webdriver-control-flow) documentation page should clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

this way worked for me:

```js
element(by.binding('Promotion.PrometricID')).getText().then(function (value) {
                console.log(value);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
element(by.model('Promotion.PrometricID')).getText().then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as the rest except with `await`

```
let text = await element(by.binding('Promotion.PrometricID')).getText();
console.log(text);
```